fsck : Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt
So I have a dual boot laptop (Win10 & ubuntu) which is UEFI boot based and has 2 physical ssd's in. After trying to shrink my ubuntu partition (sda6 below) and booting ubuntu, the ubuntu kernel starts to load, and after a while I'm dropped in a busybox rescue shell (because fsck wants to be run after the resize, as init hook script)
Sadly fsresize and other utils are not in the distributed busybox so I booted up from an USB live gparted stick and got access to some other tools like gdisk, lsblk, testdisk, parted and so on.
The partition layout is following :

root@debian:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0 463.4M  1 loop /usr/lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
                                      /run/live/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
sda           8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0   260M  0 part
├─sda2        8:2    0    16M  0 part
├─sda3        8:3    0 105.9G  0 part
├─sda4        8:4    0  23.5M  0 part
├─sda5        8:5    0  47.1M  0 part
├─sda6        8:6    0 131.4G  0 part
└─sda7        8:7    0   800M  0 part
sdb           8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   0 465.8G  0 part
sdc           8:32   1   3.7G  0 disk
└─sdc1        8:33   1   3.7G  0 part /usr/lib/live/mount/medium
                                      /run/live/medium
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
mmcblk0     179:0    0  14.6G  0 disk
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  14.6G  0 part

where /dev/sda6 is the problematic ubuntu partition.
from the gparted usb live cd I tried a recovery process with fsck :

root@debian:~# fsck.ext4 /dev/sda6
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 35389440 blocks
The physical size of the device is 34451766 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes

one of the solutions on the net is to resize the partition using resize2fs, which doesn't work :

root@debian:~# resize2fs -f /dev/sda6
resize2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/sda6 to 34451766 (4k) blocks.
resize2fs: Can't read a block bitmap while trying to resize /dev/sda6
Please run 'e2fsck -fy /dev/sda6' to fix the filesystem
after the aborted resize operation.

I tried fsck with other superblocks too (32768... etc ) but they all threw the same error.
So I checked the partition table, which gives :

root@debian:/home/user# gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 500118192 sectors, 238.5 GiB
Model: SanDisk SD9SB8W2
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 0AE22A81-8CBF-4E26-BD23-C0B1279204CA
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 500118158
Partitions will be aligned on 2-sector boundaries
Total free space is 15338 sectors (7.5 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          534527   260.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          534528          567295   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   3          567296       222707711   105.9 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   4       222709090       222757289   23.5 MiB    0700
   5       222757290       222853679   47.1 MiB    EF00  EFI system partition
   6       222853680       498467812   131.4 GiB   8300
   7       498479104       500117503   800.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition

Command (? for help):

I could see the end of partition 6 is not before the beginning of part 7, so I deleted the partition and recreated it, now part 6 ends just before part 7 (498479103)
After that this partition change, fsck keeps throwing the same error.
In dmesg there's an error about bad geometry on /dev/sda6
I have backups so that's not the big problem, and to my surprise testdisk can read, access and copy all of my data (advanced -> file system options) to /dev/sdb1 (other disk in the same system)

Disk /dev/sda - 256 GB / 238 GiB - CHS 31130 255 63

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
  1 P EFI System                  2048     534527     532480 [EFI system partition]
  2 P MS Reserved               534528     567295      32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
  3 P MS Data                   567296  222707711  222140416 [Basic data partition] [OS]
  4 P MS Data                222709090  222757289      48200 [HIVE-CONFIG]
  5 P EFI System             222757290  222853679      96390 [EFI system partition]
> 6 P Linux filesys. data    222853680  498467812  275614133
  7 P Windows Recovery Env   498479104  500117503    1638400 [Basic data partition]

 [  Type  ] >[Image Creation]  [  Quit  ]
                                Create an image

gparted or parted refuse to do something with the partition because it has errors on it.
No volume groups where in use. At least the original fstab doesn't mention those.
Is there someone who knows a miracle solution to fix this without doing a complete reinstall, like rebuilding the file system ? Or rebuilding (a) superblock(s) ?

Just go back to an older drive image, which should restore everything as it was. A 500 GB image should restore in <<1/2 hour.

For people who have a similar problem :

The user space fuse-ext2 tool has an option -o debug so one can mount a raw dd file even if it has errors in the file bitmaps. This worked for me, so in the end I could easely copy all files from the raw image file. ( https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2 ).
Next command worked like a charm.


fuse-ext2 -v raw_image_file.dd /mnt/point -o debug


debugfs (the tool, not the mount option) can be used to open raw dd files with errors by using the -c option in the open command. (-c stands for catastropheous mode and skipe reading bitmaps). (worked also for me, but wasn't scriptable)
kstatx can be used to automatically detect and map partitions in a raw dd file.

